# Katalon runtime engine integration with Jenkins remotly

Tags: jenkins, katalon-studio

I have following queries regarding Katalon. Can you please let me know the possibalities?

1. We are trying to run Katalon studio, runtime engine on one VM, while Jenkins running on another VM. In order to communicate between these two VMs, what ports need to be opened?
2. Katalon runtime engine provides local command execution. This command will be invoked by Jenkins. But in our case, Jenkins and Katalon are different machines. How we can invoke katalon command on the remote machine?

Thanks !

Comment: You could split this into two questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can clone the katalon project to the Jenkins machine and then run the tests using jenkin's [katalon plugin](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/jenkins-plugin-windows.html).
Don't forget to specify the location of the katalon project using the `projectPath` flag:
`-projectPath="%KATALON_DIR%\QA.prj"`

Answer (score 0):

Try master and Slave configuration, this will help.

master machine is your jenkins.
Slave machine is your katalon.

Through this you can execute.